# Subset Duplicated Values >10

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

I am looking at a data frame and trying to subset rows that have the same pressure value for more then 5 rows or delete rows that do not have 5 duplicate pressure values...

```
File    Turbidity   Pressure
 1      3.2         46
 2      3.4         46
 3      5.4         46
 4      3.2         46
 5      3.1         46
 6      2.3         46
 7      2.3         45
 8      4.5         45
 9      2.3         45
 10     3.2         44
 11     4.5         44
 12     6.5         43
 13     3.2         42
 14     3.1         41
 15     1.2         41
 16     2.3         41
 17     2.4         41
 18     2.1         41
 19     1.4         41
 25     1.3         41
```

So basically trying to keep rows that have a pressure of 46 and 41 and delete rows in-between. This is a small portion of my dataset and just need code that will basically keep rows with 5 or more duplicate pressure values and delete others.

Comment: Is pressure monotonically decreasing? Trying to figure out if we might see `46` further down in the table...

Comment: @MichaelChirico - that's a good point. `rle` or similar suggests itself if there are going to be repeated values. `r <- rle(dat$Pressure); dat[rep(r$l >= 5,r$l),]` maybe?

Comment: From what I understand, OP is interested in `Turbidity` values that have at least 5 observations at a given `Pressure` level

Comment: Thug life without `dplyr` `na.omit(do.call(rbind, by(df, df$Pressure, function(x) ifelse(nrow(x)>5, list(x), NA))))`

Comment: @Vlo - no need to get that fancy - `dat[with(dat, ave(Pressure,Pressure,FUN=length)) >= 5,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
#Groups: Pressure
#
#   File Turbidity Pressure
#1     1       3.2       46
#2     2       3.4       46
#3     3       5.4       46
#4     4       3.2       46
#5     5       3.1       46
#6     6       2.3       46
#7    14       3.1       41
#8    15       1.2       41
#9    16       2.3       41
#10   17       2.4       41
#11   18       2.1       41
#12   19       1.4       41
#13   25       1.3       41
```

Comment: Threw me an error

> prof %>% group_by(prof$Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5)
Error in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq(list(X = 258:1000, File = c(1L,  : 
  object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found

Comment: Try: `prof %>% group_by(Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5)`

Comment: error > prof %>% group_by(prof$Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5) Error in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq(list(X = 258:1000, File = c(1L, : object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found

Comment: do *not* use `group_by(prof$Pressure)` but `group_by(Pressure)`

Comment: > prof %>% group_by(Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5)
Error in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq(3L >= 5, <environment>), error = .rcpp_error_recorder),  : 
  object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found

Comment: Try `install.packages("Rcpp")`

Comment: Worked. Thanks for walking me through it.

Comment: Another quick question... Lets say I wanted to get the mean for all columns by using all rows that have the same pressure values?

Comment: Assuming you still want to subset for groups >= 5 and you do not want the mean of the `File` column but all others, you could do: `df %>% group_by(Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean), -File)`

Comment: Thanks for that. Anyway to get the file name on those files though?

Comment: Something like this ? `df %>% group_by(Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5) %>% summarise(Turbidity = mean(Turbidity), File = toString(File))` or would you prefer another format like `df %>% group_by(Pressure) %>% filter(n() >= 5) %>% mutate(Mean_Turbidity = mean(Turbidity))`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution (relies crucially on Pressure not repeating itself later on):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,if(.N>=5) .SD,by=Pressure]
```

---

Addendum:

If you expect `Pressure` values to repeat later on, e.g.:

```
df<-data.frame(File=c(1:19,25:28),
           Pressure=rep(c(46:41,46),c(6,3,2,1,1,7,3)))
```

Then you'll need to use `rleid` in order to keep only groups of at least 5 *in a row* (no gaps):

```
setDT(df)[,ct:=rleid(Pressure)][,if (.N>=5) .SD,by=ct]
```

Comment: `dat[,if(.N>=5) .SD, by=Pressure]`

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, I needed to add more than one column to my test `data.table` in order for that to work (o.w. returns nothing)

Comment: my first ugly solution, e.g. :P

Comment: `dat[,if(.N>=3) .I,by=var]` would work and just add a row index column, but that seems a bit ugly.

Comment: `dat[,if(.N>=5) var,by=var]` obviates the index column, but is still ugly

Comment: @Arun I thought of using your suggestion (`by=rleid(Pressure)`) but what's returned is `rleid(Pressure)`; `Pressure` itself is not returned unless you add that to the return list. So I stuck with my original thought to add the `ct` variable--depends on OP's needs for later analysis.

Comment: You can add `.SDcols` to include `pressure`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using base R:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10, Pressure=c(rep(1,5),6:10))
p.counts <- table(df[,"Pressure"])
good.pressures <- as.numeric(names(p.counts))[p.counts>=5]
df.sub <- df[df[,"Pressure"]%in%good.pressures,]
```

Note that I'm using `df` as an example data set, so you can delete that first line of code and replace all instances of `df` with the name of your data.frame.